# DNN / Bootstrap-3 Navigation issue only on mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dotnetnuke

Steps to show this issue.

Go to this page of the website;

http://chartwell.com/careers/your-career-at-chartwell

shrink your browser window down to mobile size. Close the menu with the icon. The animation finishes then the nav items appear again.

I have been having a lot of issues trying to fix this issue using the CSS here that I found in another answer;

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: height 0.01s;   
    -moz-transition: height 0.01s;   
    -ms-transition: height 0.01s;  
    -o-transition: height 0.01s;  
    transition: height 0.01s;  
}
```

But I can’t seem to figure out how to get it to go away.

Is there a way to make it go off screen after the animation?

My JS skills are not great.

Comment: I personally would do the following. 1) Upgrade to a much newer version of Bootstrap.
or 2) Check out my open source DNN skin using Boostrap 3, might be better off starting with that :D (I realize this would likely be a lot of work, and not worth the effort)

Comment: Thanks for that I did actually try to upgrade bootstrap a few days ago. Ane yes we are invested in this solution at this point. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in "skin.css". Just open it and comment out or remove (display: block) in the following code, as shown below:

```
.container > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse {
 /* display: block; */
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I am still having the issue. There are two navigations the bootstrap one I am doing for the careers is the one I am having trouble with.

Comment: @Biggy I think you did not try my solution.  Therefore I downvoted your question.

Comment: Sorry about that I thought I did try it. I might have been viewing a cached version or something. I just tried it again and it seems good now! Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet sorry.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
 .navbar-collapse.collapsing .navbar-nav {
     display:none;
 }
```

to your css

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am still having the same issue!

Comment: works for me... if you want to put your code on jsfiddle i can help you

Comment: Thanks this is my first time using this so bear with me. https://jsfiddle.net/bradtacs/Lxs4v68k/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hack-y fix that I will be using for the time being. Going to close this for now.